# Shortcode Plugin to dynamically build a shortcode via `do_shortcode` not working

Tags: plugins, shortcode

Basically I want to create a plugin that provides a shortcode for use anywhere. 
This plugin will query the user's preferences and render another shortcode/plugin with proper settings (to cater content). Currently the `do_shortcode('[sub-shortcode]')` does not process the sub-shortcode and renders the plain text.

---

#### Plugin

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin stuff......
*/

function my_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null)
{
    // Query and dynamically set categories
    return 'Testing: '.do_shortcode('[cm_rss_aggregator category=ex1,ex2]');
}

add_shortcode('example', 'my_shortcode');
?>
```

On page:

```
[example]
```

Renders:

```
Testing: [cm_rss_aggregator category=ex1,ex2]
```

Expected:

```
CM RSS Aggregator to be renedered
```

This is but one example that I'll have wrapping such shortcodes - seemed the easiest as en example.
Also tried with `<?php echo do_shortcode('[sub-shortcode]'); ?>`.
Basically trying what's shown on https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes but dynamically produce the `$content`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

### Edit

This seems to be specific to how some plugins are registered, like `cm_rss_aggregator` does:

```
class Shortcode {

    const SHORTCODE = 'cm_rss_aggregator';
    public function __construct() {
        ...
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'actionAddShortcode' ) );
        ...
    }

    public function actionAddShortcode() {
        add_shortcode( static::SHORTCODE, array( $this, 'shortcode' ) 
    }

...
}
```

Any idea if this would affect it? `add_action` delaying something special? `static::SHORTCODE` doing something special I don't know about?

Comment: A copy / paste of your code works as expected for me with the built in gallery shortcode. Maybe try `shortcode_exists` inside of your own shortcode to verify that the one you're referencing was added on that request.

Comment: It does not show up as existing. Tried Gallery again and it worked and rendered. Maybe a typo earlier?! :( I'm going to update my questions with my findings - guessing it may be the way some plugins are registered.

Comment: `cm_rss_aggregator` shortcode is registered with `add_shortcode` which is the classic way. then if `do_shortcode` doesn't render it, that means that the shortcode is not active as says Milo.

Comment: Yes - `shortcode_exists` returns false, which explains why `do_shortcode` is failing. Putting the short code directly on a page works though. I'm trying to figure out why it's not available via `do_shortcode`